# Page Reloads when submit button is hit

Tags: php, html, sql, forms, submit

I am currently programming a page in which when the submit button is pressed it runs an sql script to add a form into the database. However when the submit button is pressed the page just reloads and the script is not run. The source code for the page is shown below

**addResults.php :**

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['description'])){
    if(!isset($_POST['iscorrect']) || $_POST['iscorrect'] == ""){
        echo "Sorry, data is missing. Please press back and try again.";
        exit();
    }
    if(!isset($_POST['type']) || $_POST['type'] == ""){
        echo "Sorry, there was an error. Please press back and try again";
        exit();
    }
    require_once("scripts/connect_db.php");

    $team1 = $_POST['team1'];
    $team2 = $_POST['team2'];
    $score1 = $_POST['score1'];
    $score2 = $_POST['score2'];
    $year = $_POST['year'];
    $round = $_POST['round'];

    $type = $_POST['type'];
    $type = preg_replace('/[^a-z]/', "", $type);
    $team1 = strip_tags($team1);
    $team1 = mysql_real_escape_string($team1);
    $team2 = strip_tags($team2);
    $team2 = mysql_real_escape_string($team2);
    $score1 = strip_tags($score1);
    $score1 = mysql_real_escape_string($score1);
    $score2 = strip_tags($score2);
    $score2 = mysql_real_escape_string($score2);
    $year = strip_tags($year);
    $year = mysql_real_escape_string($year);
    $round = strip_tags($round);
    $round = mysql_real_escape_string($round);


    if($type == 'mr'){
    if((!$team1) || (!$team2) || (!$score1) || (!$score2) || (!$year) || (!$round)){
        echo "Sorry, All fields must be filled in. Press back and try again.";
        exit();
        }
    }
    if($type == 'mr'){
        $previousId = mysql_insert_id();
        mysql_query("UPDATE questions SET question_id='$previousId' WHERE id='$previousId' LIMIT 1")or die(mysql_error());
    }

    if($type == 'mr'){
    $sql2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO questions (ID, Team1, Team2, Score1, Score2, Year, Round) VALUES ('$previousId', '$team1', '$team2', '$score1', '$score2', '$year', '$round')")or die(mysql_error());
    $message = 'Thank You, Your Result Has Been Added';
    header('location: addResults.php?msg='.$message.'');
    exit();
    }
$message = "";
if(isset($_GET['msg'])){
    $message = $_GET['msg'];
}

}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Add a Question</title>
<script>
function showDiv(at1,at2){
    document.getElementById(at1).style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById(at2).style.display = 'none';
}
</script>

<style type="text/css">
.content{
    margin-top:48px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:780px;
    border:#333 1px solid;
    border-radius:12px;
    -moz-border-radius:12px;
    padding:12px;
    text-align:center;

    background-image: url(/images/grass.jpg)
}
body { background: url("http://www.environ.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/football_pitch_1129.jpg") }
</style>
</head>

<body>
   <div style="width:700px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;text-align:center;">
   </div>
 <div class="content" id="mr">
    <h3>Match Result</h3>
    <form action="addResults.php" name="addMcQuestion" method="post">

    <strong>Please Enter the First Team</strong>
        <br />
        <input type="text" id="team1" name="team1">&nbsp;
      <br />
    <br />
    <strong>Please Enter the Second Team</strong>
        <br />
        <input type="text" id="team2" name="team2">&nbsp;
      <br />
    <br />
    <strong>Please Enter the Score for Team 1</strong>
        <br />
        <input type="text" id="score1" name="score1">&nbsp;
      <br />
    <br />
    <strong>Please Enter the Score for Team 2</strong>
        <br />
        <input type="text" id="score2" name="score2">&nbsp;
      <br />
    <br />
    <strong>Please Enter the Year of the Match</strong>
        <br />
        <input type="text" id="year" name="year">&nbsp;
      <br />
    <br />
    <strong>Please Enter the Round of the Tournament</strong>
        <br />
        <input type="text" id="round" name="round">&nbsp;
      <br />
    <br />
    <br />
   <input type="hidden" value="mr" name="type">
    <input type="submit" value="Add To Quiz">
    </form>
    </form><form action="menu.php"><input type="submit" value="Return to Menu"></form>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the code of addResults.php & menu.php? And avoid using mysql_* as it is deprecated as of PHP 5.5 Use mysqli_* or PDO

Comment: the code you are looking at is addResults.php and menu.php is the main menu for the site

Comment: Where is `$_POST['description']` defined?

Comment: As @relentless mentioned, I cannot find any field name = "description" then how can you expect that data will be inserted into the database. **This is your mistake**

Comment: @shd0w : I have found your mistake. If you can, then correct it or else let me know I will post it as a answer.

Comment: Yes this was the error thank you very much

Comment: Once last issue with the page, if i insert a 0 for score 1 or score 2 I am prompted by my validation that not all fields are filled in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @relentless and @MahasishShome already noticed, your update is inside

```
if(isset($_POST['description'])) {
// update ...
}
```

But there is no field named `description` in the form you submit.

You must either insert a (hidden?) field named `description` or test for another existing field.